# Copy Files to another folder PHP

Tags: php, file, copy, duplicates, directory

So, recently I am working on a small social network, and I stuck at a beginner-fail :(

When a new User is created, a new FOLDER - named like the User - is created in the current folder (/Users). In the current folder(/Users) is also a folder named PATTERN, where a index.php is included.

When a new user is created with `mkdir($Username, 0777)` I also want to COPY the index.php from the PATTERN-Folder (/PATTERN) into the new User folder (/$Username).

It just doesn't copy in my tries - how would you do that?

Comment: What did you try and what was the _exact_ result? Show us some code

Comment: can you share your code that you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [copy()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to copy a file with PHP:

```
if (!copy('PATTERN/index.php', $Username.'/index.php')) {
    echo "failed to copy file...";
}
```

If this does not work, you might have a problem with your code, access rights, or something else. Without your code and the exact description of the error message (if any) it will be hard to help you.

Comment: I actually tried that. Now I tried again and it's working fine now.
Don't know why. But thank you so much!
Accepted the Answer because you were the fastest of course ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use copy function in php

```
copy('PATTERN/index.php', 'USERNAME/index.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use copy function

```
   // Will copy abc/a.php to xyz/x.php
   copy('abc/a.php', 'xyz/x.php');
```

Docs link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Answer (score 1):

```
copy("folder1/file.format" , "folder2/file.format");
```

sample:

```
copy("../folder1/my.jpg" , "folder2/my.jpg");
```