# How to copy an image from one folder to other in php

Tags: php

I have a image named xyz.  Besides this file named xyz has unknown extension viz jpg,jpeg, png, gif etc. I want to copy this file from one folder named advertisers/images to other folder publishers/images in my website cpanl. How to do this with php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy Files to another folder PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526046/copy-files-to-another-folder-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function:

```
$srcfile = 'source_path/xyz.jpg';
$dstfile = 'destination_path/xyz.jpg';
copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use    copy() function

```
copy('advertisers/images/xyz.png','publishers/
 images/xyz.png');
```

Change the file extension, whatever it is.

If you don't know the extension, go with the wildcard. It will give you the array of all the files matching with the wildcard.

```
$files = glob('advertisers/images/xyz.*');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
    copy($file,'publishers/images/'.$file);
}
```

Comment: sir file may vary, I want to copy a image file xyz along with its extension whatever be its extension among jpg, jpeg, JPG, JPEG, png, PNG, GIF, gif etc

Comment: @John use .* In place of extension. It will copy all the files having name xyz

Comment: i used $imagePath = "/home/public_html/advertisers/images/1adfd189e18d6d101a29cfd09b0426a4.*"; but image was not copied

Comment: Use glob('xyz.*') Function to get all the files with xyz name. It will provide array containing files. And use copy function inside loop. 
http://biostall.com/using-php-to-find-files-with-name-containing-a-wildcard/

Comment: @John i have updated my answer as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your code same as below:

```
<?php
$imagePath = "../Images/somepic.jpg";
$newPath = "../Uploads/";
$ext = '.jpg';
$newName  = $newPath."a".$ext;

$copied = copy($imagePath , $newName);

if ((!$copied)) 
{
    echo "Error : Not Copied";
}
else
{ 
    echo "Copied Successful";
}
?>
```